# Circuit to drive a telegraph sounder?

Tags: circuit-design, communication

I acquired an old telegraph sounder, marked Western Electric 140 Ohms, and have a Morse code key.  What voltage should I drive the sounder with to hear the proper Morse code click sounds when keyed?  Is any additional series resistance and/or a flyback diode required in the circuit, since the sounder contains an electromagnetic coil?

Comment: First start with a variable voltage power supply of moderate current capability with the voltage turned down and ramp it up until you get a satisfying click.  Then calculate the current and design your circuit accordingly.  This isn't likely to be too critical - most small transistors or FETs can probably do it.  A flyback diode won't hurt but may not be needed if the transistor voltage limits are many times what it sees in operation.

Comment: http://www.prc68.com/I/Telegraph.shtml#Snd